# How do I look in raw code of react library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js with VScode and looking for the way to see all code inside of the method like useState(), for example.
I tried click the code and it showed me that

`function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];`

from index.d.ts file but I want to know raw code of it as vanilla script. Let me know how to find it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js` to see the code.

Comment: Oh, there it is. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Happy to help :)